# How to Make Proper Crawler with Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to make crawler using Simple HTML Dom parser.
Everything is working fine, but when I check stats from website, it shows the following

1. Unknown robot (identified by empty user agent string)
2. Unknown robot (identified by 'bot' followed by a space or one of the following characters _+:,.;/-)

I just want to use it as proper crawler with name and link back to crawler.

What am I missing here, checkout my codes below.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
set_time_limit(9000);

$context = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params($context, array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; My-bot/1.0; +https://mydomain.tld/bot'));
$html = file_get_html("https://www.google.com/", 0, $context);

foreach($html->find('a') as $link)
{   
$linkHref = $link->href;
$linkHtml = file_get_html('http://example.com'.$linkHref);  



foreach($linkHtml->find('title') as $title2)            
{
$title2 = $title2->plaintext;
$title[] = $conn->real_escape_string(trim($title2));            
echo $title2.'<br>';            
}

}   

?>
```

Comment: what if `echo $html;`

Comment: the problem is not the way of data parsing, I know how to parse data the problem is only, that how to display a proper bot name when crawling some websites.

Comment: provide me link may be I'll help you

Comment: provide you what link? My issue is to display proper bot name when I crawl some websites, issue is not some links.

Comment: That `ini_set` doesn't do anything. Google `file_get_html user agent`

Comment: i have updated my question, but still no sign of My-bot/1.0 in website statistics, is my codes ok now or still have some issues @pguardiario

Comment: It looks right to me. I prefer curl though.

Comment: ok we can use even curl with simple html dom, so then its possible to use proper bot name using curl? I mean to say, when i crawl some website, so they will understand my crawler name and link back.